# How to scroll particular views under the scrollview in ios using swift?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I have views like below 75% view is Scrollview and 25% is Bottom Imageview.

[image]

**childView which is inside scrollviews**

[image]

**My Screen UI**

[image]

I tried below code as well but not working

```
  @IBOutlet weak var Scrollview: UIScrollView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    Scrollview.contentSize.height = 1000

  }
```

> Now when keyboard is open I am not able to click **Create Button**..I
>   want to make `scroll` child view only  under the `Scrollview`..I want
>   to keep my Image in the Bottom fixed.Android I have done..please
>   anyone help me I am new to iOS...

Comment: you can use this https://github.com/Kilograpp/IQkeyboardManager.... let me know if it works or not

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @wings below answer is working fine bro...thank for your suggestions

Comment: oka..y great :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of `NotificationCenter` to receive a notification when the keyboard is open.
Add this code into your `viewDidLoad()` method:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil, queue: nil) { (notification) in
    let keyboardHeight = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue.height ?? 0.0

    Scrollview.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 0.0, bottom: keyboardHeight, right: 0.0)
}
```

Now you should be able to scroll until you see `Create Button`.

**Note:** You will have to adjust the keyboard height value in order to add the correct inset to your `Scrollview` (in your case subtract the `imageView` height from the keyboard height value). If not you will add too much inset to the scroll view.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below library it will definitely solve your problem

https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding